# Swift convertPointFromView returns NaN when move back from child view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a tutorial part of a game. When instruction button clicked, screen will move from `SKScene` to `UIViewController` for a tutorial. The problem is my `SKScene` works fine before tutorial, however when come back from the tutorial, the node can't be clicked.
This is the code to move to tutorial from SKScene:

```
let a = (self.view?.window?.rootViewController)! as! GameViewController
self.willMoveFromView(self.view!)
self.view?.removeFromSuperview()
a.showInstruction()
```

Method showInstruction in GameViewController:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let tut = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pvcTutorial") as! Tutorial
tut.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
addChildViewController(tut)
view.addSubview(tut.view)
tut.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Here is code to move back to `SKScene` from tutorial:

```
self.parentViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.parentViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
self.parentViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
```

The reason I am using parentViewController is because I use `UIPageViewControl` for tutorial. The code will remove the `UIPageViewController` to get back to GameViewController. 
How I use detect node from SKScene

```
var loc = tap.locationInView(tap.view)
loc = self.convertPointFromView(loc)
let btn = self.nodeAtPoint(loc)
if btn is SKLabelNode{
    if btn.name != nil{
        if unlockLevels.contains(btn.name!){
            let gameScene : GameScene = GameScene(size: size, difficulty: btn.name!)
            let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(2))
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
        }else{
            if btn.name == "instruction"{
                let a = (self.view?.window?.rootViewController)! as! GameViewController
                self.willMoveFromView(self.view!)
                self.view?.removeFromSuperview()
                a.showInstruction()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I made is just simple that, instead of:

```
let a = (self.view?.window?.rootViewController)! as! GameViewController
self.willMoveFromView(self.view!)
self.view?.removeFromSuperview()
a.showInstruction()
```

I changed it to:

```
let a = (self.view?.window?.rootViewController)! as! GameViewController
a.showInstruction()
```

And it worked! As far as I understand is that in my previous code I wrote made `SKScene` removed from the GameViewController. However, I am still confused that why the scene was still able to show as nothing happened but just unable to touch any node on it. Anyways, the problem fixed and any explanation would be appreciated.